# Custom validation in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

One thing I don't like about codeigniter is the validation logic being inside the controller, easily increasing and messing the code. In order to separate this logic the controller, I've created a model that imports the `form_validation library`:

```
Class BS_Validator extends CI_Model 
{ 
    protected $rules = array(); 
    protected $fields = array();

    # Get keys of fields.
    public function getStructure()
    {
        return array_keys( $this->fields );
    }

    # Validate $_POST against the rules and fields.
    public function validate()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        foreach( $this->rules as $key => $rule )
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules( $key, $this->fields[$key], $rule );
        }

        return $this->form_validation->run( $this );
    }
}
```

For each validation I extend this class:

```
class User_Create extends BS_Validator
{
    protected $fields = array(
        'name' => 'Nome',
        'email' => 'Email',
        'password' => 'Senha',
        'password_repeat' => 'Repetir senha'
    );

    protected $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[50]',
        'email' => 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[100]|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',
        'password' => 'required',
        'password_repeat' => 'required|callback_password_repeat_check'
    );

    public function password_repeat_check ($password_repeat)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Everything works like a charm, except for the custom validation method, that is never called. In this specific case, it always returns `(pasword_repeat_check)` error.

What should I do to this method be recognized?

Comment: Why you didn't create a `form_validation.php` inside the config library? So all the validation rules will kept in a single location and it is the inbuilt function by codeigniter

Comment: Since you are using Codeigniter 3 - Did you look at Callable? http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callable-use-anything-as-a-rule

Comment: Yes, and it didn't work either. Perhaps it is a problem with the wrapper  `BS_Validator` I created.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't manage to make it work this way.

The alterative I've used was to create a file `MY_form_validation.php` on `libraries` folder in order to extend the `Form_validation` class.

```
class BS_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    protected $CI;

    function __construct($rules = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($rules);
    }

    public function password_repeat ($password_repeat)
    {
        return $_POST['password'] == $password_repeat;
    }
}
```

With that I can create `rules` instead of `callback rules`, and it can be called as the following (without the need of the **callback_** prefix):

```
protected $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[50]',
        'email' => 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[100]|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',
        'password' => 'required',
        'password_repeat' => 'required|password_repeat'
    );
```